# How to use map/filter to modify contents of an array of objects?

Tags: javascript

I have the following array:

```
myarray = [
    { "key": "A" },
    { "key": "B" }
]
```

How can I use a map/filter function in JavaScript to do the equivalent of:

```
for (var i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++) {
    if ( myarray[i].key == 'B') {
        myarray[i].mark = "marked!"
    }
}
```

In my attempt, I don't get the `mark` property in the output:

```
myarray.filter((someobject) => someobject.key == 'B').mark = "marked!"
console.log(myarray) // this does not show the "mark" key.
```

NB: I want to modify the original array.

Comment: Neither `map` nor `filter` *modify* an array. They create new ones.

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have? I'd say that's the "best way", since it's obvious what the intent is.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If there is exactly one match, then you can use `find`:

```
myarray.find(someobject => someobject.key == 'B').mark = "marked!"
```

If you don't know the number of matches, then your `for` loop seems the best way to do it. Otherwise you could for instance go for `filter` and `forEach`:

```
myarray.filter(someobject => someobject.key == 'B')
       .forEach(someobject => someobject.mark = "marked!")
```

Comment: I find the find very elegant.

Comment: At the moment this worked for me `myarray.find(someobject => someobject.key == 'B')[0].mark = "marked!"`

Comment: what about immutability?

Comment: @ThanosM, the question was *"how to ... modify"*, and the question ends with *"I want to modify the original array"*. So that's *asking* for mutation explicitly.

Answer (score 5):

> What is the best way so that I can make it such that I can use a map/filter function in javascript to do the equivalent of this code?

Not all, since neither `map` nor `filter` *modify* an array. They create new ones. You could use something like

```
let newArray = myArray.map(({key} => ({key, marked: key=='B'}));
```

but the best ES6 equivalent to your code is

```
for (let v of myArray) if (v.key == 'B') v.mark = 'marked';
```

You could also use `forEach`, but I heavily recommend against disguising side effects in a functional approach:

```
myArray.filter(({key}) => key == 'B').forEach(v => { v.mark = 'marked'; });
```

Comment: I haven't understood why it's better using the for loop instead of the foreach. Can you explain it please?

Comment: @Marco Luzzara: Using a `for` is in no way better than using chainable methods. In this case, `.filter` and `.forEach` in a sequence that completely makes sense and is the reason why JS has chainable methods in the first place. All looks clean and reasonable.

Although, I'd reduce the complexity of the `.filter` example because there's no need to destructure the `item` inside the `.filter` even further to get the `key` prop. `.filter(item => item.key === 'B')` looks more readable and maintainable.

Comment: @MarcoLuzzara It's shorter, more performant, looks more imperative, and allows to use arbitrary control structures.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.